# dpinst.exe behaviour in windows 7 with standard user privilege

Tags: c, windows, winapi, windows-7, driver

I'm using dpint.exe in my driver package. I'm facing the below mentioned scenario's in Windows 7 64 bit os.

> When UAC Enabled, It works as expected in admin mode( user with admin
>   privileges ) , standard user mode and in guest mode. ( i.e., promts a
>   window asking for admin password in standard user mode and guest mode
>   ).
>
> When UAC is disabled, In Admin mode ( user with admin privileges ) it
>   "never" shows any windows saying "Do you want to allow the following
>   program to make changes to this computer". ( this behaviour also an
>   expected one!! ) "BUT IN STANDARD USER MODE WHEN I CLICK THE DRIVER
>   INSTALLER EXECUTABLE ( Which calls dpinst.exe internally ) THE SYSTEM
>   HANGS AND WHEN I TRY TO RESTART IT SAYS A BACKGROUND PROCESS IS
>   RUNNING AND DO YOU WANT TO FORCE RESTART. In guest login mode also a
>   popup occurs showing "Setup.exe stopped working". If the above problem
>   is because of "Dpinst.exe needs an admin privilege" why does windows
>   didnt show a warning message instead gets hanged??

And how to tell the user that change to administrator to continue with installation..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "tell the user that change to administrator to continue" only by detecting the credentials the user is running under. When UAC is disabled, the installation package must take care of this task and detect whether Administrative credentials will be needed to install the application. This information is often configured in the Manifest of the application to install.

A really really good [overview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.07.uac.aspx) of UAC and Manifest explains this

Comment: does the manifest helps in prompting an message box or run as admin prompt, even if the UAC is disabled and user is in standard user mode??

Comment: manifest is just (as the word said) a "declaration" of the intentions (requirements, eg. credentials, UIPI, etc...) of the image.